# How to update thumbnails of modified bitmaps when saving them in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, gallery, thumbnails

As the questions states, I want to refresh the thumbnail of the image. Once I modify the image (in `ImageView`) by increasing the `brightness`, it still has the old image `thumbnail`.

Comment: Where you want to update in your imageview or in gallery??

Comment: @kalyanpvs hi I want to update the thumbnail in the gallery

Answer (score 1):

Execute this after your image is saved..It will refresh the gallery items..

```
getApplicationContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, you can use this:

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, mediaMountUri));`

hope this can help you !